# Umbraco Installation Wizard Error- Create User step

Tags: umbraco

I'm using Umbraco 6.0.3, VS2012 and SQL Server 2008 Express I'm having a bit of trouble with the install wizard; it keeps throwing up the following error when trying to move on the 'Create User' step (step 4).

The database is being created successfully so I'm at a loss as to what is going wrong; any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Here's the stack trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   umbraco.BusinessLogic.User.setupUser(Int32 ID) +166
   umbraco.BusinessLogic.User..ctor(Int32 ID) +140
   umbraco.BusinessLogic.User.GetUser(Int32 id) +139
   umbraco.presentation.install.steps.Definitions.DefaultUser.Completed() +53
   umbraco.cms.businesslogic.installer.InstallerStepCollection.GotoNextStep(String key) +184
   umbraco.presentation.install._default.GotoNextStep(String currentStep) +70
   umbraco.presentation.install.Helper.RedirectToNextStep(Page page) +118
   umbraco.presentation.install.steps.detect.gotoNextStep(Object sender, EventArgs e) +52
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +116
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +101
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9643314
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! Sorted it!

There were lots and lots of files/ folders not included in the project and the BusinessLogic dll and xml were some of those files.

They're included now and it's working...for now!